# UITabbarController + UINavigationController creating issue for push and pop

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.5

In my iPhone application I am using `UITabbarController` + `UINavigationController`, created in `appDelegate`.

My issue is as follows:

On screen- I have `tableview`. When one selects cell I am pushing the controller to screen-B. Now without poping it if I select another tab from tabbar, then view gets refreshed but navigationbar is not getting refreshed. It displays navigationbar of screen-Bscreen-B.

Used below code but nothing seems to solve my issue:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
        {
            [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are re-using the navigation controller, if so, I think you have to explicitly update its title/bar when changing its content.
But maybe the best thing would be, if you could provide some more code, on that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this in appdelegate

```
UINavigationController *screen1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller1];

UINavigationController *Bscreen=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller2];

NSArray *tabbararray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: screen1,Bscreen,nil];


self.TabControllerObj.viewControllers=allviewcontrollers;
```

and make tabbar as root viewcontroller of your window